# Hiding dialog which invoked another dialog

Tags: c++, qt

I have a dialog from which I'm invoking another dialog. I'd like this first dialog to disappear (permanenly if pos) as soon as I show the second dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply call the [`hide()`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qwidget.html#hide) function on `Dialog1` before calling `show` or `exec` on `Dialog2`.

Comment: @webcletic thanks, superb. I's calling it after the call to the other dialog.

Answer (score 0):

You can just call the show() method of the new dialog and after that call the this->close() for the current.